# laravel 5.2 overwrite passwsord reset

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I know they are some similar questions out there, however I cant find a similar solution to what I need, I am using laravel 5.2 authentication:

php artisan make:auth

Everything is fine except I need to slightly modify when the user submit the new password
I want to add another action

So the first thing that I did was ignore the file (that I think is the one handling this)

```
/vendor/*
!/vendor/laravel

/vendor/laravel/*
!/vendor/laravel/framework/

/vendor/laravel/framework/*
!/vendor/laravel/framework/src/

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/*
!/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/*
!/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/
```

Then on ResetsPasswords.php in the function resetPassword (around line 214), I have added the code needed

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = bcrypt($password);

    //DO WHAT I NEED TO BE DONE

    $user->save();

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
}
```

But nothing is happening, even if I place a die();
So I guess this is not the method that is been called? or when my app is deploy (into heroku) this is been overwritten? if so how can I easily recreate this functionality ?

I have followed [Laravel Reset Password documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) but it is not very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was simpler than I thought, in need to write a method with the same name in the file

passwordcontroller.php in App/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    //THE NEW CODE
}
```

I also need to add

```
use Auth;
```

At the top of the file